# WebCalendar Fatal Error message

Tags: php, calendar

I recently implemented WebCalendar onto my site and for some reason it stopped working and I now receive the following message when I go to the calendar page:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 47 bytes) in /data/19/1/87/108/1902760/user/2070591/htdocs/webcalendar/includes/functions.php on line 3065

Any ideas as to why this all of a sudden appeared?

Here's a link to the WebCalendar site:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcalendar/p

Answer (score 0):

Increase the memory limit in your php config file, which is php.ini

Change the line ini_set("memory_limit","12M"); in the php.ini file to increase the memory, can be set to 15M,16M,17M, 18M etc